# Excel, Vlookup/IF/else

Tags: excel

I want to do a vlookup/if statement that follows the following logic:

```
Input to col F : If A:A = a , b , c, d , e  then 'name' & col B:B, C:C, D:D else 'name2'
```

Edit: Maybe a mapping table could help, the logic I want is, In A2, if the data is a,b,c,d or e then return a string + concatentation of B2,C2,D2 else return another string.

Sample Data, Col E here is the output I would like.

```
+-------+----+----+----+------------+
| Stack | xx | yy | zz | Coolxxyyzz |
| Over  | aa | bb | cc | Coolxxyyzz |
| Flow  | dd | ee | ff | Coolxxyyzz |
| Super | gg | hh | ii | NotCool    |
| User  | ll | mm | nn | NotCool    |
+-------+----+----+----+------------+
```

Conditions being Stack, Over, Flow are the ones I want to return a string and concatenate of B:D. If it is not Stack, Over,Flow return another string.

**adding some images to show error:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have screanshot of the data you are working with?

Comment: Honestly I'm really unclear on what your pseudocode is trying to say but vlookup is not designed to build output. It just wants a column index in the lookup table for that 3rd parameter. Are you perhaps saying that you want to lookup a value in a reference table and if found in say A7, you want to concatenate B7, C7, and D7 together with a hardcoded prefix? And if not found, return a hardcoded default value?

Comment: @excelguy It would be helpful if you provided more information including examples of **what your data looks like**, and **what you're trying to make it look like**.

Comment: @ashleedawg im going to use that as a copy/pasta

Comment: Provided more examples guys, hopefully this makes sense, can you please remove the -1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ① Hardcoded example formulas:

```
=IF(OR(A1="Stack",A1="Over",A1="Flow"),"Cool"&B1&C1&D1,"NotCool")

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--({"Stack","Over","Flow"}=A1))>0,"Cool"&B1&C1&D1,"NotCool")

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Stack","Over","Flow"},A1)))>0,"Cool"&B1&C1&D1,"NotCool")
```

---

### ② Lookup table - easier to maintain than the above as only change in one place.

If you want a lookup table, rather than hardcoding the array `{"Stack","Over","Flow"}`, you can create a dynamic named range.

1. Put your list of terms to match on in a separate column, let's say from `G1`.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open the name manager
3. Add new item. Name: `includeTerms` RefersTo:=`OFFSET(Sheet1!$G$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$G:$G),1)`. This named range will automatically extend when ever you add more rows immediately below the existing terms. No need to edit the formula.
4. Refer to `includeTerms` in place of the array,`{"Stack","Over","Flow"}`.

[image: Dynamic named range]

---

You can substitute the named range into my last 2 formulas above, or even use other formulas, such as:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,includeTerms,0)),"NotCool","Cool" &B1&C1&D1)

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,includeTerms,1,0)),"NotCool","Cool"&B1&C1&D1)
```

---

### Examples of these in sheet

*Formulas indicated in column `F` and terms to match on in column `G`):

[image: Formulas in sheet]

Note: Using OR is probably the least preferred for future maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The formulas work great! However I am having trouble with the name manager, I am getting #value errors but if I manually put in a value of A:A into this formula(`=IF(OR(A1=includeTerms),"Cool"&B1&C1&D1,"NotCool")`) instead of `includeTerms`, i get the expected result.   . In the includeterms name i have it in another sheet like so : `=OFFSET(Mappings!$BV$2,0,0,COUNTA(Mappings!$BV:$BV),1)`

Comment: Because you are starting in BV2. Try using =OFFSET(Mappings!$BV$2,0,0,COUNTA(Mappings!$BV$2:$BV$1048576),1) if you have Excel 2003  you need to change 1048576 to 65536. If still a problem I will send you a workbook.

Comment: Thanks, but I am only getting results in the first 5 rows then the rest of column is `#VALUE`, I also have 5 rows in my `includeterms` I think it may not be seeing `includeterms` all the way down in the formula and may be reading blanks under the `includeterms`

Comment: Nope. Did you press Ctrl and F3 and enter the formula? If you do, you should see that if you put your cursor in the RefersTo area, marching ants should appear around the includeTerms words.

Comment: I posted some pictures of my name manager, can you check to see if these are okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171562/discussion-between-qharr-and-excelguy).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT #1:

This formula works for the example given:

```
=IF(OR(A1="stack",A1="over",A1="flow"),"COOL"&B1&C1&D1&E1,"NOT COOL")
```

[image]

Google Sheets allows for vlookup to return multiple values

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($A$14,$A$1:$G$9,{2,3,6,7},FALSE))
```

However excel does not have this built in functionality, you will have to break up the return into separate parts. I think formula below gives an example of what you would like to see:

```
=IFERROR("NAME"&VLOOKUP($F$6,$A$1:$E$14,2,FALSE)&VLOOKUP($F$6,$A$1:$E$14,3,FALSE)&VLOOKUP($F$6,$A$1:$E$14,4,FALSE)&VLOOKUP(F$6,$A$1:$E$14,5,FALSE),"NAME2")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could there be some mapping table that could be used? For example a table with the strings I want to see in col A and anything else would be that else part (or Name2)

Comment: @excelguy ok didnt understand at first